How to connect two Wireguard networks

I have two Wireguard servers in an internal network and clients connected to them. The servers are in network (192.168.XX.XX) and can access each other. Clients are in an external network and can only access the servers.
I need to configure the network to enable clients connected to different servers access each other (CLIENT4 needs to be able to connect to CLIENT1).
I can add WireGuard servers as peers to each other and it works. But it feels wrong since in this case I have encryption in an internal network, which I do not need.
I can also use iptable rules to route traffic, but it would be hard to maintain since iptable rules do not have DNS.
What is the best way for peers connected to the first server to reach peers connected to the second server?
It feels like a relatively easy task but I can't figure it out.
Thanks.

What's wrong with good old fashioned IP routing?

Maybe this what I need. I'm not a network guy and missed this way of doing it.

Try to use classic routing here on both WireGuard servers. Servers could keep simple routing rules for the subnets of the other WireGuard network (+masquerading).
Keep in mind, that WireGuard in addition uses its own traffic policy for the nets that are allowed to get routed over the WireGuard interfaces. You would need to also list the other WireGuard network in order to have packets go through here (Option "Client allowed IPs").
Maybe you should start using tcpdump for analyzing traffic routing on the servers step by step for simple PING commands first. It sounds doable but I have not a working configuration for your scenario at hand

As mentioned by @vidarlo, I looked into ip routing and it turned to be a good option. I managed to solve the problem using them. I put the servers on the same network and added the following rules:
server1:
ip route add 10.2.0.0/16 via 10.2.0.1

server2:
ip route add 10.1.0.0/16 via 10.1.0.1

10.1.0.1 is the wireguard interface on the first server;
10.2.0.1 on the second.

Do you want client from one VPN network to reach VPN clients on the other network?
In that case: Please remember to add the other VPN subnet to the "AllowedIPsclause in each VPN client. This means you have the following line on all clients on VPN networks: AllowedIPs = 10.1.0.0/16, 10.2.0.0/16. But if you had chosen the subnets10.0.0.0/16and10.1.0.0/16instead, then it could be summarized asAllowedIPs = 10.0.0.0/15`.
